# PowerShell SQLServer.Management.Smo.Server can't connect

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to use Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.Smo.Server to connect to my MSSQL server but whatever I try it keeps erroring out with "Failed to connect to server .."

```
#Connect and run a command using SMO 
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
$sqlServer = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.Smo.Server "."

foreach($sqlDatabase in $sqlServer.databases) {$sqlDatabase.name}
```

The SQL server is running on the same computer with default settings and I tried both "." (which means localhost from what I understand) and *S6* which is the server's name. I can connect to *S6* from within *SQL Server Management Studio* just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `$sqlServer`

You may also check this out:

[SQL PS Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017)

[Import SQL PS Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/import-the-sqlps-module?view=sql-server-2014)